# Create a checkbox on server, handling function with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I had created a checkbox at the server during runtime, and populated it in a table on the webpage, and I would like to make use of it to trigger some JavaScript to handle some functions in the client.

However, I'm not sure of how to trigger the function using a checkbox created in this manner.

I understand that I can trigger the function when I declare a checkbox in this syntax.

```
asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server" Onclick="javascript:myfunction()"
```

However, this checkbox may or may not be required to be created on the webpage, and hence I'm unable to insert this hardcoded on the webpage

Is there any way which I can use to detect the status of this checkbox and trigger my JavaScript in the client? or if I can handle what I need to do at `code_behind`?

Comment: can u please share how you are creating checkbox during runtime ? `I had created a checkbox at the server during runtime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose that we are adding `CheckBox` to `td` of an table

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td id="td1" runat="server">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

and in the code behind,

```
CheckBox chkbox = new CheckBox();
chkbox.ID = "CheckBox1";
chkbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "click_Func(this);");
td1.Controls.Add(chkbox);
```

and javascript will be look like this ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function click_Func(chkbox) {
 alert(chkbox.id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a script tag on the page like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%=Checkbox1.ClientID%>').live('changed',function(){
            // Do your work here.
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: it might be getting a compile time error because u are trying to access a checkbox which is created at runtime only.

Comment: Or you can add this javascript on the page by the server when you create the textbox by c# code

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myScript", script, false);

Comment: Thats why I posted the second solution above. In the parameter script, you will have to put the whole script in the solution above in a string before passing here.

Comment: Its better to write in client side itself, But you must provide the class. Try `$('.myRuntimeChkBoxClass')` instead of `$('#<%=Checkbox1.ClientID%>')` . While creating checkbox you must set  cssclass property with `myRuntimeChkBoxClass`. Hope you got the point

Comment: Writing script on the page through code is no different, the solution you provided is just another workaround.

Comment: In my case there won't be any compile time issue happen.

Comment: But what about the checkbox? how do I ensure that checking the checkbox will hook onto the javascript?